# pandas dropping columns based on column name

Tags: python, pandas

all

Let's say there is a df with some column names - in my case the names are numeric values.  For example, column named 1000, 1001, etc.  I need to drop everything that doesn't pass a certain filter test - in my case, all columns with names less than a certain value.  Lets say less than 1500...

I know how to do this directly (by listing every column), or by calling drop in a loop, but it seems very inefficient.  I'm having syntax difficulties expressing it..

I have tried something like this:

```
df.drop(df.columns[x for x in df.columns.values<str(1500)], axis=1))
```

or

```
df.drop(df.columns.values<str(1500)], axis=1)
```

but these are obviously wrong.

Please, advise!
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simpliest is create boolean mask and then select with loc:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(10), index=[0]);
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

#inverting boolean mask with ~
print (df.loc[:, ~(df.columns < 8)])
     8    9
0  NaN  NaN

print (df.columns >= 8)
[False False False False False False False False  True  True]

print (df.loc[:, df.columns >= 8])
     8    9
0  NaN  NaN
```

What is same as [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) by filtered column names:

```
print (df.columns[df.columns < 8])
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')


print (df.drop(df.columns[df.columns < 8], axis=1))

     8    9
0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider a dataframe with column names 0 to 99.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If you want to drop the column names less 30,

```
df = df.drop((x for x in df.columns.tolist() if x < 30), axis = 1)
```

returns

```
    30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  ... 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If your columns are of the type object, convert them first using

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

first build a list of cols you want to drop (loop thru the columns, see if they match the criteria), then drop all cols from that list at once.

Comment: I could do that, but I was wondering if there's an inline option.  Something like this:  df.drop(df.columns[x for x in range(1000,1499)], axis=1)